# Is "crooner" old-fashioned and humorous?

Tags: nouns

My dictionary tells me "crooner" is old-fashioned and humorous.  I was wondering why "crooner" is humorous?  I would like to hear from native speakers how you view/use this word.  Here's an [example of use](http://www.cbsnews.com/2100-3445_162-597089.html):

> Movie star Debbie Reynolds and crooner Eddie Fisher are Fisher's parents. In the 1950s, they were America's sweethearts. But, Eddie left Debbie for bombshell Elizabeth Taylor when Carrie was just a toddler. – CBS-Sunday Morning

Comment: I'm not totally clear if you're asking if the *word* crooner is old-fashioned and humorous, or if an *actual* crooner (or his style of singing) would be considered old fashioned and humorous. For what it's worth, none of the few dictionaries that I have close by have a note about 'crooner' being either humorous or old-fashioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is an old-fashioned term...think Bing Crosby, Frank Sinatra, etc. But it is occasionally applied to current artists, such as Michael Buble, probably because they remind listeners of the classic crooners. (I believe the term is used only for male singers.)

I don't think the term originally had the connotation of humor. However, crooners sang popular songs in a syrupy manner (in some listeners' opinions), and their style of singing has been parodied in recent decades. [See *Saturday Night Live*'s sketch of Will Ferrell as Robert Goulet (a crooner).](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=zhx2w0nQrB8)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. What about *croon* itself, and its other derivatives then?

Comment: Do you mean are croon and its other derivatives also old-fashioned and humorous? I would say they are considered old-fashioned, not really humorous. Also, *croon* is probably a more commonly used word than *crooners*, as in "croon a lullaby." Interesting NGram: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=croon%2Ccrooner&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3